# A null-homologous knot in the solid torus

Tags: algebraic-topology, knot-theory

The following picture is from Saveliev's book [Lectures on Topology of 3-manifolds](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/9783110250367/html), page 130:

[image: knot]

He says that this dark-black knot in the solid torus $S^1 \times D^2$ is homologous to $S^1 \times \{ 0\} \subset S^1 \times D^2$, i.e., null-homologous.

How can we prove such a claim? Can we have a right to use tools of knots in $S^3$?

Comment: That's an odd definition of "null-homologous."  Usually null-homologous means something that's equivalent to the statement that the knot bounds an oriented surface in the ambient space.  In any case, two knots are homologous if they are equivalent when you also allow crossing-change moves.

Comment: Thanks, Kyle! How we can allow crossing-changes? Also, this is independent of the ambient space?

Comment: Knots in $S^1\times D^2$ can be represented using diagrams in $S^1\times [0,1]$, just like the diagram on the annulus in your question. The Reidemeister theorem for this space is that two knot diagrams correspond to ambiently isotopic knots iff there is a sequence of Reidemeister moves constrainted to the annulus. By "crossing change," I really mean just switch a crossing from over to under (or vice-versa) in a diagram. It's a purely local change and does not depend on the ambient space. I should say that for homology there's also the saddle move (think solutions to $t=x^2-y^2$, varying $t$).